# ошибка "sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file" pyrogram на хостинге

Tags: python, pyrogram

```py
from pyrogram import Client
from pyrogram.handlers import MessageHandler
from pyrogram.errors import FloodWait
from pyrogram.types import Message
from pyrogram import filters
import time
import random

api_id = 23071494
api_hash = '6d90d9fae0a669e6a51fe55ba370e355'

client = Client(name='Ramir ADMIN', api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash)

def all_message(client: Client, message: Message):
    message.forward(-1002087001002)

client.add_handler(MessageHandler(all_message, filters.chat(chats=6357965364)))

def handle_message(client: Client, message: Message):
    if message.text == "Бот привет":
        select = random.randint(1, 5)
        if select == 1:
            message.reply('Добрый день!', quote=True)
        elif select == 2:
            message.reply('Здравствуйте, какое у вас сегодня настроение?', quote=True)
        elif select == 3:
            message.reply('Здарова!', quote=True)
        elif select == 4:
            message.reply('Добрый день, я бот Ramir!', quote=True)
        elif select == 5:
            message.reply('Здравствуйте, сегодня отличный день.', quote=True)
    elif message.text == "Бот авто ферма":
        id = 0
        Auto_farm(client, message, id)
    elif message.text == "Бот свойства":
        ping = random.randint(100, 3000)
        message.reply(f'Свойство подключения к телеграм:\nМост 1:obfs4 144.24.128.153:39001\nМост 2:obfs4 88.99.13.4:2010\nМост 3:obfs4 45.79.251.210:80\nПинг: {ping}', quote=True)
    elif message.text == "Бот стоп ферма":
        id = 1
        Auto_farm(client, message, id)
    elif message.text == "Бот ссылка":
        datafile = ("database/moder.txt")
        database = open(datafile, 'r')
        moder = database.read()
        message.edit(f"Напишите модератору в личные сообщения, Сейчас работает модератор\n{moder}")
    elif message.text == "Бот как дела?":
        message.reply("У меня все хоршо. У вас как?", quote=True)
    elif message.text == "Бот":
        message.reply("Работаю. Ошибок не было", quote=True)


@client.on_message(filters.command("с", prefixes=".") & filters.me)
def type(_, message):
    orig_text = message.text.split(".с ", maxsplit=1)[1]
    text = orig_text
    tbp = ""
    typing_symbol = "▒"
 
    while(tbp != orig_text):
        try:
            message.edit(tbp + typing_symbol)
            time.sleep(0.01)
 
            tbp = tbp + text[0]
            text = text[1:]
 
            message.edit(tbp)
            time.sleep(0.01)
 
        except FloodWait as e:
            time.sleep(e.x)

@client.on_message(filters.command("модер", prefixes="Бот ") & filters.me)
def type(_, message):
    print("Выполнение")
    client.delete_messages(message.chat.id, message.id)
    orig_text = message.text.split("Бот модер ", maxsplit=1)[1]
    text = orig_text
    tbp = "" # to be printed
    datafile = ("database/moder.txt")
    database = open(datafile, 'w')
    database.write(text)

@client.on_message(filters.command("mega", prefixes="///") & filters.me)
def hack(_, message):
    perc = 0
 
    while(perc < 100):
        try:
            text = "‍ Подключение к TOR ..." + str(perc) + "%"
            message.edit(text)
 
            perc += random.randint(1, 30)
            time.sleep(2)
 
        except FloodWait as e:
            time.sleep(e.x)
    number = random.randint(1, 5)
    if number != 5:
        message.edit("‍ Подключение к TOR 100%\n Мост активирован!\n")
        time.sleep(3)
 
        message.edit("‍ Подключение к TOR 100%\n Мост активирован!\n Подключение к ///MEGA ...")
        perc = 0
    
        while(perc < 100):
            try:
                text = "‍ Подключение к TOR 100%\n Мост активирован!\n Подключение к ///MEGA ... " + str(perc) + "%"
                message.edit(text)
    
                perc += random.randint(1, 20)
                time.sleep(2)
    
            except FloodWait as e:
                time.sleep(e.x)
        time.sleep(1)

        while(perc < 100):
            try:
                text = "‍ Подключение к TOR 100%\n Мост активирован!\n Подключение к ///MEGA 100%\nВход в систему... " + str(perc) + "%"
                message.edit(text)
    
                perc += random.randint(1, 20)
                time.sleep(2)
    
            except FloodWait as e:
                time.sleep(e.x)
        time.sleep(1)
        if random.randint(1, 3) != 1:
            while(perc < 100):
                try:
                    text = "‍ Подключение к TOR 100%\n Мост активирован!\n Подключение к ///MEGA 100%\nВход в систему ... " + str(perc) + "%"
                    message.edit(text)
        
                    perc += random.randint(1, 20)
                    time.sleep(2)
        
                except FloodWait as e:
                    time.sleep(e.x)
            time.sleep(1)
            message.edit('‍ Подключение к TOR 100%\n Мост активирован!\n Подключение к ///MEGA 100%\nВход в систему 100%\n✅Авторизованы в систему, панель управления отправлена в "Избраное"')
        else:
            message.edit('‍ Подключение к TOR 100%\n Мост активирован!\n Подключение к ///MEGA 100%\nВход в систему ERROR\n❌Хост закрыл соединение!')
 
        
    else:
        print(number)
        message.edit('‍ Подключение к TOR 100%\n❌Ошибка соединения TORAPI ERROR')

 
    
 
async def main(message):
    async for message in client.iter_messages(6357965364, limit=1):
        await message.forward_to(-1002087001002)

def Auto_farm(client: Client, message: Message, id):
    message.reply('Выполнение')
    try:
        if id == 1:
            message.reply('Комманда отключена❌')
        else:
            while True:
                message.reply('ферма')
                time.sleep(14500)
    except:
        while True:
            message.reply('ферма')
            time.sleep(14500)
    

client.add_handler(MessageHandler(handle_message))



try:
    client.run()
except:
    client.run()
```

ошибка в коде при работе на хостинге. Когда на компьютере то работает.
ошибка:

```
  File "/home/Ramirchick/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyrogram/clien
t.py", line 616, in load_session
    await self.storage.open()
  File "/home/Ramirchick/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyrogram/stora
ge/file_storage.py", line 58, in open
    self.conn = sqlite3.connect(str(path), timeout=1, check_same_thread=Fal
se)
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```